# Stitch together separate Aurelia apps

Tags: single-page-application, aurelia

Is it possible to have a common aurelia shell application that can load and navigate between separately hosted child applications?

So far I have only seen this question answered by having multiple divs with the 'aurelia-app' attribute in them.  But this assumes that each app will be served from the same server instance and have files/routing co-located there.

What I am after is a way to have separate SPA's each possibly self-hosted on different machines (virtual or otherwise) that can act as stand-alone applications or be embedded in a parent SPA that can navigate between these SPA's and possibly coordinate passing data between them.

Is this possible in Aurelia or any other SPA framework?

Comment: You can just treat your applications as components.  This should be fine.  Can you provide more context or a sample repro of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I haven't started building anything yet.  After looking through the docs, it appears the only way to achieve what I want to do would be to create a navigation component that would be used by all of my separate applications.  This component would connect to a common database which would store information about all registered apps and their respective locations (server/port) so that the navigation component could navigate between them and pass data from one application to the other in a standardized way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Aurelia object's setRoot() method to change what is loaded for into the  defined in index.html.  I use this in my app to switch between the full-screen login mode and the application mode with full nav-bar.

```
private aurelia: Aurelia;

showLogin() : Promise<any> {
    return this.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('Login', 'login'));
}

showApplication() : Promise<any>  {
    return this.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('Client', 'application'));
}

setRoot(root: string) {
    // NOTE: Aurelia will call router.deactivate() & router.reset() if there is an existing root
    // this.router.navigate('/', { replace: true, trigger: false });
    return this.aurelia.setRoot(root);
}
```